# Using getchar to open a file from the console

Tags: c, getchar

Okay,hello guys. My intention is to ask the user for a file name and by using pipe mechanism to open the file. For now I have only this code. How to actually perform the piping and where is the information stored - ./myprog < text, where text is the input that should be taken by getchar. Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char input;
    input=getchar();
}
```

Comment: "How to actually perform the piping" -- this is done for you by the shell. The standard input for `./myprog` is the contents of `text`. "Where is the information stored" -- not at all, it is read from `text` (as you requested). This happens without your C program being aware of it. You just read from `stdin`.

Comment: I formated the code properly and made `main` have the recommended signature (if no arguments are passed). Learn from it, don't get too fancy with formating. Read more about proper formating styles **for C**. Note that I left en error: check which return-type `getchar` returns and **why**.

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting the standard input from a file is performed by the shell: you specify the filename on the command line.

You can also read a filename from the user with `fgets()` and open the file in the program.  You can use `freopen()` to specify the stream to use, for example you can re-use `stdin` as the `FILE*` stream.